# How to get every subset of a vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

What's the easiest/most idiomatic way to get every subset of a vector in Rust?

```
let v = vec![1,2,3];
assert_eq!(subsets(v), [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're searching for is called the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of a vector.

Here's the code to generate the powerset of a slice of a vector.

```
fn powerset<T>(s: &[T]) -> Vec<Vec<T>> where T: Clone {
    (0..2usize.pow(s.len() as u32)).map(|i| {
         s.iter().enumerate().filter(|&(t, _)| (i >> t) % 2 == 1)
                             .map(|(_, element)| element.clone())
                             .collect()
     }).collect()
}   

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3];
    println!("{:?}", v);
    let pset = powerset(&v);
    println!("{:?}", pset);
}
```

See it in action [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=74ca28d761fcdd997626cbab96d69408&version=stable&backtrace=0).

If you'd like a vector of references in order to prevent copies, you could make a simple change:

```
fn powerset<T>(s: &[T]) -> Vec<Vec<&T>> {
    (0..2usize.pow(s.len() as u32)).map(|i| {
         s.iter().enumerate().filter(|&(t, _)| (i >> t) % 2 == 1)
                             .map(|(_, element)| element)
                             .collect()
     }).collect()
}
```

See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2e02d1a96d1e04e014b7b88c456e8d5c&version=stable&backtrace=0) for gist.

Comment: I think you could avoid the `Clone` bound by returning a `Vec<Vec<&T>>` instead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed! Good catch and thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

If order of elements of output is not crucial, and output like this: `[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` is acceptable, you can do something like this:

The underlying idea is very simple:

1. Start with an empty set: `[[]]`
2. Copy all your elements to a temporary variable that will be updated by adding the first element (`1`) to every subset -> `[[1]]` and add that to the original vector: `[[], [1]]`
3. Do step 2 for the second element (`2`): `[[], [1], [2], [1,2]]`
4. Do step 2 for the third element (`3`): `[[], [1], [2], [1,2], [3], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]`

For example:

```
fn powerset(s: &[i32]) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    let mut subsets: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![];
    let empty: Vec<i32> = vec![];
    subsets.push(empty);

    let mut updated: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![]; 

    for ele in s {
        for mut sub in subsets.clone() {
            sub.push(*ele);
            updated.push(sub);
        }
        subsets.append(&mut updated);
    }
    subsets
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3];

    let subs = powerset(&my_vec);
    println!("{:?}", subs);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more functional flavoured solution that uses the `itertools` crate.

I am new to Rust so FYI my decisions around cloning/borrowing/ownership/etc may not be the best, but hopefully the gist of the implementation is helpful.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn subsets<T: Clone>(items: Vec<T>) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    (0..=items.len())
        .map(|count| items.clone().into_iter().combinations(count))
        .flatten()
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    // for example ...
    let it = subsets(vec![12, 24, 36]);
    println!("{:?}", it);
}
```

Comment: More idiomatic rust would remove the return state in subsets so it's implicit. That looks pretty nice though. I like the use of `combinations` in there, it keeps the actual logic simple.

Comment: @timlyo thanks, what do you mean by 'remove the return state in subsets'?

Comment: Sorry typo'd that. I meant remove the `return` statement. If you remove the `return` and the semi colon then it'll be converted to an implicit return so it'll look like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=280506eaca8ad2a4f21b768e803b2592